# Multiple domain user login access control in drupal7

Tags: php, drupal-7

E.g. My site has two subdomains : first_domain and second_domain.

And My site has three roles:admin, site-manager, editor.

I hope:

User with admin can login first_domain, can't login second_domain. (When user visit second_domain user status is not logined and not lost first_domain logined status)

User with site-manager can login second_domain, can't login first_domain.

User with editor can login first_domain and second_domain.

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this module, i think it would help you, you might have to twist a configuration based on requirement but could be good base module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_roles

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage session in every domain and check that if one user is login in first domain and session is created then the second user redirects to a page where it say already login.

I cannot write a code here for you for making sessions. You can create session in php.

Let me know if you are not able to understand the logic.

Comment: Is their any feasible solution available to solve this?like drupal modules or optimized code to check this

Comment: Not really. This the only solution you can achieve this.

Comment: if you like my solution, then accept the answer please :-)